# Django View gettig MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django-views

Getting MultiValueDictKeyError application raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Can any one please guide what is wrong in code. i am new in Django.

view.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
            status = request.POST['Status']
            remark = request.POST['Remark']
**            AttachDoc = request.FILES['AttachDoc']**
            try:
                apptracking = Applicationtracking1.objects.create(application1=application1, Remark=remark, Status=status, AttachDoc = AttachDoc)
```

Can any one please guide what is wrong in code. i am new in Django.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: After executing the above code getting MultiValueDictKeyError